# Javascript StackOverflow Error

Tags: javascript, class, stack-overflow

I was hoping I could get some help figuring out why a bit of my code is causing a stack overflow.

Code in question:

```
var ClassCreator = {
    create: function(class_object,ParentClass){
        var created_class = null;


        created_class = function(){        
            if(arguments.length == 0){
                this.constructor();
            }else{
                this.constructor.apply(this,arguments);
            }        
        };

        this._grantInheritance(created_class,ParentClass);
        this._grantMethods(created_class,class_object);    

        return created_class;
    },

    _grantInheritance: function(created_class,ParentClass){
        if(ParentClass){
            created_class.prototype = ParentClass.prototype;
            created_class.prototype.BaseClass = ParentClass;
        }
    },

    _grantMethods: function(created_class,creation_object){
        //If there's no constructor provided, add a default constructor.
        if(!creation_object.constructor){
            creation_object.prototype.constructor = function(){};
        }

        //Add the creation_object's methods to the class we're creating.
        for(var property in creation_object){
            created_class.prototype[property] = creation_object[property];
        }
    }
};

var SuperSuperObject = ClassCreator.create({
    constructor: function(){
        document.write("Hello");
    }
});

var SuperObject = ClassCreator.create({
    constructor: function(){
        this.BaseClass.call(this);

        document.write(" ");
    }
},SuperSuperObject);

var RegularObject = ClassCreator.create({
    constructor: function(){
        this.BaseClass.call(this);

        document.write(" World");
    }
},SuperObject);

var test = new RegularObject();​
```

As far as I can understand, when I call this.BaseClass.call in RegularObjects constructor, it attempts to call RegularObjects constructor again, thus causing the stack overflow.  Why it's calling RegularObject's constructor and not SuperObject's constructor, I don't know.  Any ideas?

---

**Edit**:
My solution, in case anyone would like it in the future:

```
var ClassCreator = {
    __PROTOTYPE_CONSTRUCTOR_SIGNAL__:  "1821fe18a870e71b29a6219e076b80bb",

    create: function(class_object,ParentClass){
        var created_class = null;


        created_class = function(){
            var call_class = null;


            if(arguments.length == 1){
                if(arguments[0] == ClassCreator.__PROTOTYPE_CONSTRUCTOR_SIGNAL__){
                    if(this.prototypeConstructor){
                        this.prototypeConstructor();
                    }

                    return;
                }
            }


            if(!this.__construct_stack){
                this.__construct_stack = 0;
            }
            call_class = this;
            for(var counter = 0;counter<this.__construct_stack;counter++){
                call_class = call_class.BaseClass.prototype;
            }
            this.__construct_stack++;


            if(arguments.length == 0){
                call_class.constructor.call(this);
            }else{
                call_class.constructor.apply(this,arguments);
            }


            return this;
        };


        this._grantInheritance(created_class,ParentClass);
        this._grantMethods(created_class,class_object); 

        return created_class;
    },

    _grantInheritance: function(created_class,ParentClass){
        if(ParentClass){
            created_class.prototype = new ParentClass(this.__PROTOTYPE_CONSTRUCTOR_SIGNAL__);
            created_class.prototype.BaseClass = ParentClass;
        }
    },

    _grantMethods: function(created_class,creation_object){
        //If there's no constructor provided, add a default constructor.
        if(!creation_object.constructor){
            creation_object.prototype.constructor = function(){};
        }

        //Add the creation_object's methods to the class we're creating.
        for(var property in creation_object){
            created_class.prototype[property] = creation_object[property];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that sets the "BaseClass" property.

Comment: It's `ClassCreator._grantInheritance()` which sets `created_class.prototype.BaseClass`.

Comment: you need to open up a javascript console in the browser and step through your code. Fairly easy to find from there. `this.constructor();` calls `RegularObject.constructor` which calls the `this.constructor();` etc etc.

Comment: That's what I've done.  And it led me to what I know now, that for some reason, it's calling teh constructor on the RegularObject.

Comment: It's all good.  I've got to wonder what's with all the (2) downvotes though.  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

In RegularObject's constructor, you're setting the context of its BaseClass method to RegularObject. Now when you enter the SuperObject's constructor, "**this**" will be referencing RegularObject(the same object you just came from) and in turn you will be calling RegularObject's BaseClass method again (making it identical to `this.BaseClass.call(this);` in RegularObject's constructor). And because you "call" BaseClass with the same object again, you get a stackoverflow / infinite loop.

Not the best explanation, but perhaps some examples would help...

**Example**

Here's a simplified code block that highlight what's happening

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GVkDv/1/

```
var base = function(){
    //"this" now references the object we just came from along with it's methods 
    //and properties. 
    this.BaseClass.call(this); 
}

base.prototype.BaseClass = function(){ alert('made it to the base'); }

var derived = function(){
    alert('About to stackoverflow'); 
    this.BaseClass.call(this);//"call" keeps the context to the object we're on 
}

derived.prototype = new base(); //construct base the first time. 1st Alert.
derived.prototype.BaseClass = base; 

var x = new derived(); ​
```

### Solution

To fix it, you'll need to maintain a context object to reference the instance of the inherited base class.

**Example:**

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bboone/GVkDv/6/

```
var superbase = function(){
    var ctx = this; //maintain context of the initialized prototype object

    this.init = function(){
        alert('superbase'); 
    };

    this.init(); 
}

var base = function(){
    var ctx = this; //maintain context of the initialized prototype object

    this.init = function(){
        //ctx and this are referencing different objects
        ctx.BaseClass.init.call(this); 
    };

    this.init(); 
}

base.prototype = new superbase(); //construct superbase the first time. 1st Alert.
base.prototype.BaseClass = base.prototype;    

var derived = function(){
    var ctx = this; 

    this.init = function(){
        //ctx and this are referencing different objects
        ctx.BaseClass.init.call(this); 
    };

    this.init(); 
}

derived.prototype = new base(); 
derived.prototype.BaseClass = derived.prototype; 

var x = new derived(); 
x.init(); //call all the way down the inheritance chain.
```

I should point out there are plenty of well documented/vetted inheritance patterns.

Some examples:

- John Resig - [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)
- Douglas Crockford - [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)

Comment: Ha ha.  That's exactly right.  I was actually just realizing that a second ago.

Comment: Edit:  I've added my solution, if you'd like to see it.